# Changing text color in WebStorm

Tags: ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Could you please tell me where I can find a place in the WebStorm settings where I can change the color of the text of the application itself, not the code. I want to change to white instead of the standard gray. In the default theme "High contrast" color is white, in all other dark themes it is gray. Can you tell me if there is such a twist or perhaps somehow you can change this color through the theme, then what tools exist for this?

My theme where the text color needs to be changed:

[image: my theme where the text color needs to be changed]

"High contrast" theme in which the text color is white:

[image: "High contrast" theme in which the text color is white]

Comment: Such a color is provided by the Theme itself, it's not configurable via GUI (at very least in all standard themes). https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/themes-getting-started.html **Material Theme UI Plugin** allows extra control / customization and might have an option for that (I'm not using it so cannot say for 100%, but seems possible via Custom Theme; it's a PAID plugin): https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui and https://material-theme.com/docs/configuration/custom-themes/